# Add/Override behavior on Jaxb generated classes by extending them

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling, xjc

I have a web server responding with xml data and a client consuming it.
Both share the same domain code. One of the domain objects looks like this:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
@XmlRootElement(name = "image")
public class Image {

    private String filename;
    private ImageTypeEnum type;

    @XmlElement(name = "imageUri")
    public String getAbsoluteUri() {
        // some complex computation
        return uri;
    }
}
```

When I try to unmarshal the response from the server into this object, since there's no setter for absoluteUri, I don't have the imageUri in the class. So I extend it like this:

```java
public class FEImage extends Image{
private String imageUri;
    public String getAbsoluteUri() {
        return imageUri;
    }
    public void setAbsoluteUri(String imageUri) {
        this.imageUri = imageUri;
    }   
}
```

My ObjectFactory

```java
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {
    public Image createImage(){
        return new FEImage();
    }
}
```

My code to unmarshal is here:

```java
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.ObjectFactory",new ObjectFactory());         
((JAXBElement)unmarshaller.unmarshal((InputStream) response.getEntity())).getValue();
```

However, the `setAbsoluteUri` doesn't seem to be getting called in `FEImage` while unmarshalling. When I add a dummy `setAbsoluteUri` in `Image.java`, everything works as expected.

Can someone tell me how can I cleanly extend from `Image.java`?

Answer (score 5):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

---

A JAXB implementation is not required to use the `ObjectFactory` class when instantiating an object.  You can configure instantiation to be done via a factory class using the `@XmlType` annotation:

```java
@XmlType(factoryClass=ObjectFactory.class, factoryMethod="createImage")
public class Image {

    private String filename;
    private ImageTypeEnum type;

    @XmlElement(name = "imageUri")
    public String getAbsoluteUri() {
        // some complex computation
        return uri;
    }
}
```

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-factory-methods.html

If you do the above, then your JAXB implementation will still use the `Image` class to derive the metadata so it will not solve your problem.  An alternate approach would be to use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

Better still, when a property on your domain object does not have a setter, you can tell your 
JAXB implementation ([EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy), Metro, Apache JaxMe, etc) to use field (instance variable) access instead using `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Image {
}
```

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

---

**UPDATE #1**

If you are not able to modify the domain objects, then you may be interested in MOXy's externalized metadata.  This extension provides a means via XML to provide JAXB metadata for classes where you cannot modify the source.

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/MOXy/Runtime/XML_Bindings

---

**UPDATE #2 - Based on results of chat**

***Image***

Below is the implementation of the `Image` class that I will use for this example.  For the complex computation of `getAbsoluteUri()` I simply add the prefix "CDN" to the filename:

```java
package forum7552310;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
@XmlRootElement(name = "image")
public class Image {

    private String filename;
    private ImageTypeEnum type;

    @XmlElement(name = "imageUri")
    public String getAbsoluteUri() {
        return "CDN" + filename;
    }

}
```

***binding.xml***

Below is the MOXy binding document I put together.  In this file I do a few things:

- Set `XmlAccessorType` to `FIELD`
- Mark the absoluteURI property to be `XmlTransient` since we will be mapping the `filename` field instead.
- Specify that an XmlAdapter will be used with the `filename` field.  This is to apply the logic that is done in the `getAbsoluteUri()` method.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum7552310">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Image" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="filename" name="imageUri">
                    <xml-java-type-adapter value="forum7552310.FileNameAdapter"/>
                </xml-element>
                <xml-transient java-attribute="absoluteUri"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

***FileNameAdapter***

Below is the implementation of the `XmlAdapter` that applies the same name algorithm as the `getAbsoluteUri()` method:

```java
package forum7552310;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class FileNameAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return "CDN" + string;
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String adaptedString) throws Exception {
        return adaptedString.substring(3);
    }

}
```

***Demo***

Below is the demo code demonstrating how to apply the binding file when creating the JAXBContext:

```java
package forum7552310;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, "forum7552310/binding.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Image.class}, properties);

        File xml = new File("src/forum7552310/input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Image image = (Image) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(image.getAbsoluteUri());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(image, System.out);
    }
}
```

***jaxb.properties***

You need to include a file named `jaxb.properties` with the following contents in the same package as your `Image` class:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

***input.xml***

Here is the XML input I used:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<image>
    <imageUri>CDNURI</imageUri>
</image>
```

***Output***

And here is the output from running the demo code:

```
CDNURI
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<image>
   <imageUri>CDNURI</imageUri>
</image>
```

Comment: That may not be possible as I do not have control over Image.java.  Can this be done on FEImage.java? Moreover, notice that absoluteUri is NOT an instance level field in Image.java. It is generated on the fly.

Comment: @Sam - I have added more detail to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I've started to implement this but keep running into javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "eclipselink-oxm-xml" is not supported. I have specified jaxb.properties in the same location as FEImage.java, which is com.example.fe.domain.image. I also tried putting it one level above and also in the classpath, to no avail. Any hints?

Comment: Do you have the necessary EclipseLink jars on your classpath?  Are you running inside or outside an application server?

Comment: Yes, I have all the necessary eclipselink jars in my classpath. running inside tomcat 6.

Comment: @Sam - Since you will be using the metadata file to map the `Image` class you need to put the mappings document in the same package as the `Image` class.  For more information see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: I do not have access to the Image class, it comes in as a jar. I've extended Image into FEImage. I'm trying to convert an xml that I receive from the server into FEImage. I've added a method in FEImage and I've mapped it in the bindings.xml. I am expecting to take advantage of JAXB annotations on Image as well as the XML bindings on FEImage in this way. Also, I've added a jaxb.properties in the same package as FEImage. I tested it with System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(FEImage.class).getClass()); However, I still get class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3836/discussion-between-sam-and-blaise-doughan)

Comment: @Sam - Based on the results of our chat I have updated my answer with a more detailed example.