# Adding extra methods to a JAXB class generated from schema

Tags: java, jaxb

Here's a trivial excerpt from my XSD file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="ns"
    xmlns:tns="sns" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <element name="document">
        <attribute name="title" use="required"/>
  </element>
</schema>
```

I use the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to generate Java classes from this.  The `Document` class has a `getTitle()` method to return the text of the `title` attribute.

I want to add an additional method to `Document`:

```
public String getStrippedTitle() {
   return getTitle().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
}
```

I want my extra method to appear on the unmarshalled object (rather than me just calling it or writing a wrapper class) because I want to pass the top-level unmarshalled object off to a string template and have it iterate over sub-elements calling my extra method.

I found [instructions](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.5/docs/release-documentation.html#compiling-xml-schema-adding-behaviors) but they tell me to set a property on the `Unmarshaller` and my (Mac OS X, Java 7) implementation doesn't appear to support any properties.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the link the Brian Henry gave, I found I could perform binding customization inline in my schema file to do what I wanted.  The effect is exactly the same as Brian's solution, but it doesn't require a reference to a reference to `com.sun.xml.internal`.

First, the schema file gets modified somewhat:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="ns"
    xmlns:tns="sns" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
jaxb:version="2.0">

  <element name="document">
      <annotation>
          <appinfo>
              <jaxb:class implClass="DocumentEx" />
          </appinfo>
      </annotation>
      <attribute name="title" use="required"/>
  </element>
</schema>
```

When the schema gets compiled into Java code, the generated ObjectFactory will refer to `DocumentEx` instead of `Document`.  `DocumentEx` is a class I create, which looks like this:

```
public class DocumentEx extends Document {
   public String getStrippedTitle() {
       return getTitle().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
   }
}
```

`Document` (the class I'm extending) is still generated by the schema-to-Java compiler.  Now when I unmarshall a document I actually get a DocumentEx object:

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.xml");
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setSchema(testSchema);
    DocumentEx doc = (DocumentEx)unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

There is some (hard-to-parse) documentation for this at [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148576) and some helpful examples at [O'Reilly](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/10/jaxb.html?page=2).

Comment: This doesn't work for me:
`<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schema/experiment.xsd" node="/descendant::xs:element[@name='task']">
    <jaxb:class implClass="br.ufop.decom.TaskNode"/>
  </jaxb:bindings>`
A class/interface with the same name "br.ufop.decom.Task" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.

Comment: I don't know. Your `implClass` and the class in the error message don't match, so I suspect the problem is beyond the scope of the snippit you pasted here? You might need to ask this as its own question to get enough space to describe your problem.

Comment: The problem is that the XSD generated by the Intellij seems not to be compatible with the jaxb annotations. I generated the XSD in another format `Global elements/Local types` and the annotation works well

Answer (score 2):

You could try to update the property name you're seeing in the linked doc.  try this instead:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.FACTORY
```

or

```
"com.sun.xml.internal.bind.ObjectFactory"
```

I'd guess that will get you past the PropertyException I figure you're seeing.  The most thorough answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552310/add-override-behavior-on-jaxb-generated-classes-by-extending-them), suggests this is not guaranteed to work, but worth trying since you've come this far.  Source code, as far as I looked (not far) appears to support this property.

Comment: This works.  Thanks!  Do you have any suggestions for a better overall method of unmarshalling an XML file into Java classes with some extra methods?  I was trying SAX before JAXB, but it felt like I was just writing my own (crummy) JAXB implementation.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot - You don't need to generate the JAXB model from an XML schema.  You can start from whatever object model you want and use the JAXB annotations to configure the XML mapping.